# How to map a property to database table column explicitly in codefirst Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

While running add-migration in from my model class
The below property Journy type not added in up method ..how can i add to DB.and also if i add manually in up method .In Next add-migration command it is generating dropping column command  in database how can i overcome this.

```
    public string JournyType { get { return OneWay ? "OneWay" : "ReturnJourny"; } }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool OneWay { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool Return { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
public bool JournyTypeBool{ get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public string JournyType { get { return JournyTypeBool? "OneWay" : "ReturnJourny"; } }
```

Now if you execute Add-Migration, you can see column "JournyTypeBool" in AddColumn in Up() and DropColumn in Down(). JournyType is not mapped but you can get JournyType value "OneWay" or "ReturnJourny" based on the column value "JournyTypeBool".